# Connecting printer to a D-Link DSL-2750B Router/Modem

Tags: router, printer, modem, print-server

I've looked around on the internet and on the router page, but I couldn't find out how to enable the print server on the router I have. I am trying to connect a PSC-1410v USB printer to a DSL-2750B Router and Modem combo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up from the CD. If you have installed that, a D-link icon should appear in the system tray. Have a look at pg 121 in the [User Manual](http://www.engin.com.au/Downloads/DSL-2750B_T1_Manual_v3.00%28AU%29.pdf%E2%80%8E).